# Ambiguity Problems with MultiParamTypeClasses

Tags: haskell

I've got a typeclass that's defined like this:

```
class (Eq a, Show a, Typeable a) => Condition v a where
```

(and some methods)

I wanted to write a function that takes two Conditions that both have the same 'v'.

```
analyze :: (Condition v a, Condition v b) => a -> b -> Bool
```

(Return type made Bool for simplicity)

But when I try to compile this, I get

```
Could not deduce (Condition v0 b)
  arising from the ambiguity check for ‘analyze’
from the context (Condition v a, Condition v b)
```

So it's clearing not deducing what I wanted to say, and instead has introduced another type variable v0.

Could you explain what's wrong with the formulation of the type signature as I've written it and how to fix it? Do RankNTypes address the problem?

Comment: `Condition v a` requires both `v` and `a` to be resolved. Since `v` is not mentioned in the right hand side of the `=>` in analyze, the compiler has no way to pick the correct `v`. It is the same as having `foo :: Show a => ()` or `foo :: Condition a x => x -> Bool`. How do you select an `a`? I don't know what the interpretation of `Condition` is, but it may be the case that `v` should be determined by `a` - if this is the case, then you can write `class Condition v a | a -> v`, which is called a functional dependency.

Comment: I think that's the right answer here. Adding it fixes my code. Add it in as an answer and I'll tick it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Condition v a` requires both `v` and `a` to be resolved. Since `v` is not mentioned in the right hand side of the `=>` in `analyze`, the compiler has no way to pick the correct `v`. It is the same as having `foo :: Show a => ()` or `foo :: Condition a x => x -> Bool`. How do you select an `a`? I don't know what the interpretation of `Condition` is, but it may be the case that `v` should be determined by `a` - if this is the case, then you can write

```
class Condition v a | a -> v
```

which is called a functional dependency.

Answer (score 1):

A functional dependency, as described in another answer, could solve the problem. I'd like to point out another option: using a type proxy.

```
class (Eq a, Show a, Typeable a) => Condition v a where
  -- Introduce v into the type of analyze, without demanding that a
  -- value of type v be provided; instead, just give some value which
  -- indicates v as a type parameter (like a Proxy, for instance).
  analyze :: (Condition v a, Condition v b) => proxy v -> a -> b -> Bool

instance Condition Bool Bool where
  ...
instance Condition Int Bool where
  ...

-- Use a proxy to pick out the type of v.
exampleInt = analyze (Proxy :: Proxy Int) True False
exampleBool = analyze (Proxy :: Proxy Bool) True False
```

Since you're using `Typeable`, you probably have `Proxy` in scope already, as `Data.Typeable` exports it.

Using functional dependencies rules out the above example: you cannot have two instances of `Condition` for the same `a`. Maybe that's fine, but if not, consider using a type proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to use [type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Comparing_type_families_and_functional_dependencies) instead of functional dependencies (which also eliminates the need for multiparameter typeclasses):

```
class (Eq a, Show a, Typeable a) => Condition a where
   type V a :: *

analyze :: (Condition a, Condition b, V a ~ V b) => a -> b -> Bool
```

Answering the comment from OP: Type families "might also be regarded as an alternative to functional dependencies, but provide a more functional style of type-level programming than the relational style of functional dependencies". They are later addition to GHC so many older libraries still use functional dependencies. There are some differences between TF and FD (e.g. the way overlapping instances are handled) but I think it is generally accepted that for newer code TF is preferable approach.
Here is a report outlining the experience of [converting FD to TF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies_vs._type_families)

Comment: This interesting. Can you explain why you'd choose one approach and not the other? Functionally they seem pretty similar, but I've been a lot more code (like MonadReader that goes with the functional dependencies approach)